# Excel 365 - Search table return true for each row

Tags: excel, filter, excel-formula, office365, spreadsheet

TRUE & FALSE Table

[image]

Hey All,

I need to return ALL the rows where TRUE is found so I can put it through a FILTER function.

E.g

`S2:Z2` does not contain TRUE value return FALSE for Row 2

`S3:Z3` contains a TRUE value return TRUE for Row 3

Thanks!

EDIT: Example of returned data

DATA Returned in AB

[image]

[Returned Pending](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IYMUp.png)

Comment: What will be for other row? Suppose you have 2 or 3 row with all `FALSE` value. Then what will be result?

Comment: If there are ANY TRUE values in the row then it returns TRUE otherwise it is FALSE

Comment: Can you an example of your output from given data manually?

Comment: I added a manual example to the OP as DATA Returned in AB.

Comment: Check my answer please.

Comment: So, column `AB` is exactly your output? If any column contain `Pending` then result will be pending, right?

Comment: correct, refer to my current solution as it can be used in a filter functions to pull the 'Pending' rows

Comment: You can use a helper column to filter your desired result easily. Otherwise filter formula will be long but can be done.

Comment: Have a look on my edited answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/228421/discussion-between-harun24hr-and-oracle).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use:

[image]

Formula in `H1`:

```
=FILTER(A1:E5,MMULT(--A1:E5,SEQUENCE(COLUMNS(A1:E5))))
```

**NOTE:** `WAAR` is the Dutch equivalent of `TRUE` and `ONWAAR` the equivalent to `FALSE`.

---

Or, if it's "Pending" you are looking for:

[image]

Formula in `H1`:

```
=INDEX({"","Pending"},1+(MMULT(--(A1:E5="Pending"),SEQUENCE(COLUMNS(A1:E5)))>0))
```

Comment: Obviously this is better than my answer. I have to explore `MMULT()`.

Comment: @Harun24HR, not necessarily better but it atleast is less verbose =)

Answer (score 1):

Try below formula-

```
=IF(SUM(--S2:Z2)=0,FALSE,TRUE)
```

[image]

> EDIT: Try below formula. Here `P` represents `Pending`.

```
=FILTER(S2:Z6,(S2:S6="P")+(T2:T6="P")+(U2:U6="P")+(V2:V6="P")+(W2:W6="P")+(X2:X6="P")+(Y2:Y6="P")+(Z2:Z6="P"))
```

[image]

Comment: This works, but it needs to do it for the entire table for the filter function

Comment: I think only true false is not your actual data. Can you please post a sample of your actual data then output result manually? The it would be easier for us to understand to provide solution.

Comment: I have added the data. I need to use a filter function to identify rows that are pending. Which is where column AB comes in and provides the array necessary for the filter function. EDIT: I did not want to have a formula for each row as the data is dynamic so the amount of rows will constantly change.

Comment: Yeah, I came to the same conclusion using IFS/IFERROR. I was hoping to have some sort of index array to make the formula much smaller and potentially allow for future columns to be added easily. Thanks for your help @Harun24HR

Answer (score 0):

This is the only solution I could come up with but it seems like an awful way around it.

=IFERROR(IFS(S2:S5000="Pending", TRUE,T2:T5000="Pending", TRUE,U2:U5000="Pending", TRUE,V2:V5000="Pending", TRUE,W2:W5000="Pending", TRUE,X2:X5000="Pending", TRUE,Y2:Y5000="Pending", TRUE,Z2:Z5000="Pending", TRUE),FALSE)

Up to row 5000 being an arbitrary number that I know the data will never exceed.